# Common practice for variables with similar names in constructor parameter and as a property

Tags: c#, class, variables, parameters, constructor

Is there a "correct" way to name a variable when it is being passed in a constructor to a property? Example (in c#):

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int index;

    public MyClass(int i)
    {
        index = i;
    }
}
```

When the two variables are the "same", is it common to name one more concisely, etc.? I want to be consistent at least, but I'm as to whether there is an accepted way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public MyClass(int index)
{
    this.index = index;
}
```

This is at least the common way of doing in Java, and I guess it's [the same in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx). It makes the name more meaningful than `i`, and uses the same name as the property to designate the same thing.

Comment: The common way in C# is to name the variables lowercase and name the properties uppercase. This way you could simply write `Index = index;`.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor recommends private fields of a class to be camelCase prefixed them with _ (`_index` in your case). They recommend parameters to be camelCase without the underscore.

As mentioned in comments, there is no MSDN-recommended standard for private fields.

Comment: Recommended by whom? Not by Microsoft, as far as I can tell, nor by StackOverflow users.

Comment: Refactor. Microsoft doesn't have a recommendation. Having said that, it's quite sensible.

Comment: It is certainly a sensible naming scheme, I'll agree, but not the only one, and not used to an extent that I would call it "the recommended standard" without qualification.

Comment: Edited to reflect source of recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as you wrote

or

below can be another option if the variable names are same

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int index;

    public MyClass(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can name them the same. Use this to clarify what you're doing.

```
this.index = index;
```

If you make a distinction (which I do no recommend) it's better to be most explicit about the parameter name passed to the method instead of your internal name. If other programmers use your class then at least they know what the parameter means. So if you want to distinct:

```
public MyClass(int index)
{
  i = index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **you should focus on making the "visible" variable more readable** (in this case, that's the constructor's parameter). After all, this is what the users of your class will see when typing out.

**Yes, there is a correct way** to avoid such dilemmas, which is to follow the naming conventions established for your language. For example, in C# it's a convention that private fields begin with an underscore. There's probably something equivalent to Java.

That being said, it's definitely possible to differentiate between fields and local variables by explicitly using `this` to reference fields (a practice that's appropriate when there's a naming ambiguity).

Answer (score 0):

There are set of coding standards in .NET defined in MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

but for the total list of guidelines:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The C# standard would write your code like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  public MyClass(int index) {
    Index = index;
  }
  public int Index {
    get { return _index; }
    private set { _idex = value; /* Perform other actions triggered by the set */ }
  }
  private int _index;
}
```

In cases where no backing field is required the property (and backing field) can and should be simplified to:

```
public Index { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Hello am know that is old but why not _index = index in constructor

Comment: @damsan: because in that case the code `/* Perform other actions triggered by the set */ ` won't be executed. That's a defect.